# Do you still benefit from ASIs when using True Polymorph?

Tags: dnd-5e, polymorph

I've seen references to feats being retained when you are transformed via True Polymorph. Are ability score increases (ASIs) also kept? If not, that would seem to make feats a strictly better choice if you're aiming to be True Polymorphed.

Comment: Did you mean wildshape/or shapeshift?

Answer (score 8):

## No

If you are talking about ASIs you've already earned then all your ability scores get replaced (regardless of ASIs):

> The target's game Statistics, including mental Ability Scores, are replaced by the Statistics of the new form.

Feats also do not carry over with True Polymorph. Just a heads up.

Comment: It's worth adding that Feats also do not carry over when True Polymorphed, so whatever references ToryArashi read were mistaken

Comment: I think he meant to reference shapeshift