# Magic jar's interaction with ability increases and racial feats

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, racial-traits

*[Magic Jar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-jar)* p. 257 of the Player's Handbook states:

> Once you possess a creature's body, you control it. Your game statistics are replaced by the statistics of the creature, though you retain your alignment and your Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores. **You retain the benefit of your own class features.** If the target has any class levels, you can't use any of its class features.

Since you gain ability increases and feats (like Elven Accuracy) as part of your class levels, am I correct in assuming you keep them in the new body even if one of them had your ancestry as a prerequisite?

Comment: I change the title to say "class" instead of "racial" to match the question. Hope that's ok.

Comment: Actually no, because it's specific to the racial element of the feat.  I'm not confused by the class element.

Comment: Sorry. I sort of get the Elven Accuracy feat part (which is still a feat even if it has a race as a prerequisite). But "You gain ability increases as part of your class levels": This has nothing to do with racial features at all.

Comment: It's 2 separate things. I don't understand your confusion.

Comment: Related on [Do you lose racial feats when reincarnated out of your race?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120614/do-you-lose-racial-feats-when-reincarnated-out-of-your-race) and [](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111184/do-you-still-benefit-from-asis-when-using-true-polymorph)

Comment: I do think you need to ask the ability score question separately from the racial feats one. But the above related may be sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page 154 of Player's Handbook:

> You must meet any prerequisite specified in a feat to take that feat. If you ever lose a feat’s prerequisite, you can’t use that feat until you regain the prerequisite.

Since racial traits have at least a race as prerequisite and since your body is no longer of said race, you don't meet it anymore and can't use it although you retain it, to no avail...

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!